# Spark XML using xpath to produce key value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to extract the data from the xml and join the extracted data with a CSV file (example column:2).

I tried below code:

```
val input = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/hadoop/selva/Test.xml")
val xmlVal = input.values
val mapVal = xmlVal.map(x => scala.xml.XML.loadString(x))
val res = mapVal.map(x => (x \\ "ALERT" \\"property" \\"name")text)
res.collect()
Output : res3: Array[String] = Array(stackoverflowstackoverflowquery)
```

**Expected output:** I need the above value in the form of key value pair to join the data.(Spark inner join)

> Key : stackoverflow value : 1
>   Key : stackoverflow value : 1
>   Key : query value : 1

So, that I can use Spark join to join two datasets.

Comment: I tried the below code
val res = mapVal.map(x => (x \\ "ALERT" \\"property" \\"name")   
val res1 = res.map( x => for { e <- x.flatten} yield e.text)
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String]] = MappedRDD[12] at map at <console>:20
How can i create key value pair here.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Since `mapVal` consists of only one element, you have to apply `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
mapVal.flatMap(x=>(x\\"ALERT" \\"property" \\"name").map(y=>(y.text,1)))
```

Comment: scala> val res = (mapVal \\ "ALERT" \\"property" \\"name").map(x=>(x.text,1))
<console>:18: error: value \\ is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.xml.Elem]
       val res = (mapVal \\ "ALERT" \\"property" \\"name").map(x=>(x.text,1))

Comment: I have corrected my code. Does it now give the desired result?